# Алгоритм вывода людей и мест работы

Tags: php

Есть список людей и список их мест работы. Например так:

```
$persons = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'user2']
];

$jobs = [
    ['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job1'],
    ['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job2'],
    ['person_id' => 2, 'name' => 'job2']
];
```

У каждого человека может быть несколько мест работы (связь через `person_id`). Моя задача вывести их в таком формате:

```
person1(1, 2), person2(2)
job1(1), job2(2)
```

Т.е. около каждого имени человека стоят порядковые номера его мест работы. Заметьте - места работы могут повторяться, но вывестись должны без дублей. К сожалению мне не удалось придумать ни одного варианта как так можно вывести... Надеюсь на помощь или хотя-бы примерный алгоритм действий!

Comment: Я так понял - вам нужно группировать по месту работы?

Comment: @АндрейДобровольский я не уверен. Они же в разных таблицах...

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас это из БД читается? Если так, то просто сделайте один правильный SQL-запрос и будет вам счастье

Comment: @rjhdby да, из бд. А что вы подразумеваете под "правильным" запросом?

Answer (score 1):

Итерируемся по массиву  `$persons` на каждой итерации проходимся по массиву `$jobs` и находим все места работы персоны. Данные сохраняем в отдельный массив.

```
$persons = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'user2']];
$jobs = [['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job1'], ['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job2'], ['person_id' => 2, 'name' => 'job2']];
$p_j = [];
foreach ($persons as $person) {
  foreach ($jobs as $job)  {
    if ($job['person_id'] == $person['id']) {
        if (array_key_exists($person['id'], $p_j)) {
            if (!in_array($job['name'], $p_j[$person['id']])) {
                $p_j[$person['id']][] = $job['name'];
            }
        } else {
            $p_j[$person['id']][] = $job['name'];
        }
    }
  }
}
foreach ($persons as $person) {
  echo $person['name'] . '(';
  if (array_key_exists($person['id'], $p_j)) {
    echo implode(',', $p_j[$person['id']]);
  }
echo ') ';
}
echo "\n";

// user1(job1,job2) user2(job2)
```

Надеюсь для вывода второго рядка сами правки сделаете

Comment: Не все так просто. Нужны индексы мест работы. Они обязательно должны выводиться. И чтобы не было дублей.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 1
            [name] => job1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 1
            [name] => job2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 2
            [name] => job2
        )

)
Индексы разные, у $job[2] и $job[1] - 'name'  - одинаковые

Comment: Отпимально, как по мне - это группировать по пользователю (индекс массива = ид пользователя) и его места работы .
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => job1
            [1] => job2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => job2
        )

)

Comment: @АндрейДобровольский не забывайте что у каждого пользователя может быть несколько мест работы.

Comment: @DarkByte Добавил реализацию в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Немного переименуем исходные массивы:

```
$pdata = [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1'], ['id' => 2, 'name' =>'user2']];
$pjdata = [['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job1'], ['person_id' => 1, 'name' => 'job2'], ['person_id' => 2, 'name' => 'job2']];
```

---

Составим уникальный список работ с их номерами

```
$jobs = array_flip(array_unique(array_column($pjdata, 'name')));
```

Сделаем заготовку для массива `$perons` вида `[1 => ['name' => 'user1', 'jobs' => [] ], ....]`

```
$persons = array_map(function($p){ 
                 return ['name' => $p, 'jobs' => []];
              }, array_column($pdata, 'name', 'id'));
```

Теперь заполним поля `jobs`, пройдясь по массиву:

```
foreach($pjdata as $d){
    $persons[$d['person_id']]['jobs'][ $jobs[$d['name']] ] = $d['name'];
}
```

и собственно осталось вывести результат в нужном виде:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array  (
            [name] => user1
            [jobs] => Array (
                    [0] => 'job1'
                    [1] => 'job2'
                )    
        )    
    [2] => Array (
            [name] => user2
            [jobs] => Array (
                    [1] => 'job2'
                )    
        )    
)
```

Вывод, наверное, труда не составит, номера работ можно склеить через  `implode(',', array_keys($p['jobs']))`

Answer (score 0):

Если отталкиваться от того, что вся информация забирается из БД.

```
$personToJobs = [];
$jobToPersons = [];
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT person_id, name FROM persons_job_table');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(!isset($personToJobs[$row['person_id']])) $personToJobs[$row['person_id']] = [];
    if(!isset($jobToPersons[$row['name']])) $jobToPersons[$row['name']] = [];
    $personToJobs[$row['person_id']][] = $row['name'];
    $jobToPersons [$row['name']][] = $row['person_id'];
}
```

Вывод

```
foreach($personToJobs as $person => $jobs){
    echo "person".$person."(".implode(',', $jobs).")".PHP_EOL;
}

foreach($jobToPersons as $job => $persons){
    echo $job."(".implode(',', $persons).")".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Что это вообще? О_о Где вы взяли две таблицы с работой? Я такого не говорил. И почему вы не выбрали поле `name` нигде? Я может непонятно объяснил? Вот это то что выводится например `job1(1)`  это `name(index)`. Аналогично и с person, только из другой таблицы имя уже выбирается.

Comment: @DarkByte это пример того, что такие задачи надо решать начиная с правильного запроса к БД. Названия таблиц я, естественно додумал исходя из вашего коммента `Нужны индексы мест работы.`. Индекс - это число, а `job1` - это, все же, ключ.

Comment: @DarkByte переделал под ваши реалии

Comment: `job1` это не ключ. Это место работы. Индекс места работы в моем понимании это примерно следующее: `array_search('job1', array_unique($jobNames))`

Comment: @DarkByte `array_search` не гарантирует повторяемость. От слова совсем. При одном запуске он может вам выдать индекс 1, при втором - 101. Будет лучше, если вы добавите в вопрос точную постановку задачи - что конкретно вы пытаетесь этим кодом достичь.

Comment: Да мне не важен порядок мест работы. От слова совсем. Мне важно лишь сопоставить места работы и людей. Чтобы около каждого имени человека стояли индексы его мест работы так как они посчитались в данный момент. Пускай даже в следующий раз они поменяются местами, но сопоставление должно быть.

Comment: @DarkByte почему именно индекс, а не `name`?

Comment: Что почему? Не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: @DarkByte Ладно, сделаем вид, что просто не сошлись в терминологии. :) Короче, если принять, что SQL-запрос правильный, то мой код создает два массива. В первом ключи - идентификаторы пользователей, а значения - массивы с их работами, а во втором ровно наоборот. Вам это нужно было?

Comment: Нет. Ладно, я кажется сам придумал как сделать.